How to make all lines in a buffer have equal height?
The context
I'm using term in GNU Emacs 29.3. I usually use tmux inside *terminal* (i.e. the buffer that is opened by M-x term) and in my tmux configuration I made the tmux status bar to be displayed at the top.
I have noticed that sometimes the tmux status bar disappears when it is being run in a *terminal* buffer and some characters are shown.
Reproducing the issue
Let's first create a simple file that has 100 lines of character that is shown with a different height. You can create such file in a GNU/Linux based system with the following command: for i in $(seq 1 100); do echo "$i ⟳" >> /tmp/a.txt; done. Note the character ⟳.

Launch emacs -Q
M-x term
Open tmux
Move the tmux status bar to the top. To do this, press C-b : to open the tmux command line and evaluate set-option -g status-position top (see screenshot below).



Execute cat /tmp/a.txt in the terminal

At this point, the tmux status bar has disappeared (see screenshot below).

Additional information
I tried reproducing the issue in gnome-terminal or kitty (see screenshots below.) Those terminal emulators displayed the status bar at the top when the content of the file /tmp/a.txt were shown.
The image below shows the behavior in gnome-terminal. In contrast to the behavior in *terminal*, kitty displays the tmux status bar at the top when the content of /the file tmp/a.txt is printed.

The image below shows the behavior in kitty. In contrast to the behavior in *terminal*, kitty displays the tmux status bar at the top when the content of the file /tmp/a.txt is printed.

The question
I think that the tmux status bar would be shown at the top if all lines have the same height. So my question is: How to make all lines in a buffer have the same height?
Personal thoughts
I believe the tmux status bar at the top disappears because some characters (such as ⟳) are assigned a height that is greater than the height for ASCII characters in Emacs. When they are shown in the *terminal* buffer, Emacs assumes that all lines have the same height which is not necessarily true.
Given that this issue doesn't happen in gnome-terminal and kitty, I suspect that those terminal emulators use an algorithm to make all characters have the same height so that all lines have the same height and thus, all lines fit in the window.
Related links

A question in Stack Overflow asked on Mar 28, 2013 where a user reports that some Greek characters affect line spacing in Emacs. The accepted answer recommends finding a font that contains all the characters needed.
A question in Stack Overflow asked on Nov 15, 2013 where a user asks why some line heights vary. The accepted answer states that removing some of the characters in the line solves the problem.
A question in Stack Overflow asked on Nov 8, 2012 where a user asks how to restrict the font height in Emacs.


You already have the answer right there: find a single font that contains all the characters you want to display. That will ensure that all of them have consistent metrics, such as line height, x–height, stroke width, and so on. Of course it is a pretty big job for a font designer to do a good job across every script in Unicode because there are so many of them. Therefore the fonts that have wide coverage tend to be more perfunctory than fonts with narrow coverage.
The terminal emulators both cheat by drawing all characters into a consistently–sized character cell even when they come from proportional fonts. Sometimes this causes other artifacts such as clipping or overlapping characters, but it has the benefit of being very very fast to draw text that way. The Emacs GUI, on the other hand, draws each span of text at its own preferred width and height, so sometimes the line height will vary like that. This has the advantage of allowing for buffers containing mixed monospaced and proportionally–spaced text to look more natural, as well as allowing for text shaping in scripts that need it, such as Greek, Hindi, Arabic, etc.

After reading your suggestion, I spent some time looking for bitmap fonts that define glyphs for most characters.  I found GNU Unifont. This font has a single size: 16x16. I'm looking for a smaller font. Previously, I had used 5x7.bdf from the misc-misc font. Do you know a bitmap font that has the same size 5x7.bdf and define glyphs for most characters in Unicode?

Lol, no. Bitmap fonts are the worst.
